# Scrolling a webpage on tablet devices

Tags: javascript, android, ipad, browser, tablet

I'm coding a site in PHP with some JavaScript that causes the page to scroll down slowly to the bottom of the page when a user clicks a button:

```
scrollBy=300;
window.scrollBy(0,1);
scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',scrollBy);
```

This works brilliantly on the desktop, but on both iPad and Android devices it seems to carry out about 5 iterations of the scroll and then stops (there is a separate function that halts the scroll if the user hits another button, but that isn't being called).

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I've looked around quite a while but its an outstanding bug thats starting to get to me!

Thanks a lot!

Dan

**/edit**

If when the script is running (and has halted) I scroll to the bottom of the page, then up a little, the scrolling continues for again for about 10 iterations then stops. If I then scroll up again, the same occurs.

Comment: did you try to scroll based on the screen size ? that could explain the issue.

Comment: No I haven't - the above is the only scroll snippet I've used. I haven't looked in to using screen dimensions as I just wanted it to continue scrolling till it can't scroll no more! (which sounds a bit bad thinking about it now....)